# proof that directed graph doesn't exist

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that the directed graph that has 5 vertices where - *three vertices have indegree 3, two have indegree 0; three vertices have outdegree 3, two have outdegree 0* - doesn't exist.

From my understanding, as the number of odd degrees vertices is odd - 3, and even the sum of degrees is 9, such graph shouldn't exist. But those zeroes kinda confuse me so I am not sure if sum & count prove it.

How to can I prove this?

Comment: The total sum of indegrees is 9, so as the sum of outdegrees. The number of edges is 9. There should be another reason for non-existence of such graph.

Comment: @user376343 oh! for directed graph I should include in and out degrees for the count. So basically as it has 18 sum of degrees and 9 edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are $5$ vertices, and only two with in-degree $0$ or out-degree $0$, there must be at least one with both in-degree and out-degree equal to $3$.  Let $x$ be such at vertex.  Then there are $3$ vertices $y_1,y_2,y_3$ such that there is an edge from $x$ to $y_i, i=1,2,3.$

We have a contradiction already.  Do you see it?

Comment: @sauspats on what basis you assume that there must be at least one with both in-degree and out-degree equal to 3?

Comment: @lapots 3+3 gives 6 (3 vertices with indegree 3 + those with outdegree 3), but the graph has just 5 vertices...

Comment: @user376343 still don't get it. probably I'll try to draw it.

Comment: @lapots There are $5$ vertices.  There are two with in-degree $0$ and two with out-degree $0$.  Even if no two have both in-degree $0$ and out-degree $0,$ that makes only $4$ vertices.  The fifth one has in-degree $3$ and out-degree $3$.

Comment: @saulspatz probably I am missing some property of graphs. basically if one node has 0 indegree, it means that for the remaining 4 nodes one cannot have indegree 3 without other three nodes having indegrees at least 1? thus contradiction as we need one node with indegree 0?

Comment: @lapots No, it's just counting.  For each node, write down the pair (in-degree, out-degree).  Five vertices give $5$ pairs, so $10$ numbers.  Four of the numbers are $0$, $6$ of them are $3$.  At least one pair must have two $3$s.

Comment: @saulspatz so basically if its counting it just works for such small numbers? if the original data was for 100 nodes it would be impossible to check?

Comment: @lapots It depends on the numbers.  Try this: there is no digraph with $99$ vertices such that $49$ have in-degree $0,$ $49$ have out-degree $0,$ $50$ have in-degree $51,$ and $50$ have out-degree $51.$

Comment: @saulspatz there should be some property that would allow to solve that effortlessly. Something from combinatorics maybe...

Comment: It's **exactly** the same argument as in the case you posed originally.  There can be no more than $98$ vertices that have in- or out-degree $0$, so there is at least one with in-degree and out-degree $51.$

Comment: @saulspatz I kinda get it...It is something akin intersection of sets?

Comment: @lapots Maybe, but I don't see how, myself.

Comment: @saulspatz if we imagine the indegrees as set { 3,3,3,0,0 } and set of outdegrees as { 3,3,3,0,0 }  granted default case is impossible (no way to draw it), then we are bound to have a case where entry from indegree set is 3 and the same entry in outdegree set is 3 no matter how we try to permutate it.

Comment: @lapots Yes, that is correct.